# i have an error when use chart on laravel

Tags: laravel, chart.js

Can someone can help me? I get an error when I try to use a chart.

> Undefined variable: label (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\latihan_penjualan\resources\views\home.blade.php)
>   in 15bd1eeee4b4d1b903b52322d785ce7ce1ab31d2.php line 31

This is my controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $kategori = DB::table('kategoris')->get();
    $data = [];
    $label = [];
    foreach ($kategori as $i => $v) {
        $value[$i] = DB::table('produks')->where('id_kategori',$v->id)->count();
        $label[$i] = $v->nama;
    }
    return view('home');
    $this->with('value',json_encode($value));
    $this->with('label',json_encode($label));
}
```

And this is my view:

```
<div id="container" style="width: 100%;">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.chartjs.org/dist/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var color = Chart.helpers.color;
  var barChartData = {labels: {!! $label !!},
  datasets: [{
    label: 'Produk Per Kategori',
    backgroundColor: color(window.chartColors.red).alpha(0.5).rgbString(),
    borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
    borderWidth: 1,
    data: {!! $value !!},
  }],
};
window.onload = function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: barChartData,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      legend: {
          position: 'top',
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
          text: 'Grafik Data Produk'
      }
    }
  });
};
</script>
```

I already declared the variable `$label`. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this working example:
https://therichpost.com/laravel-chartjs-with-dynamic-data-working-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix this part after `return view('home');`

```
public function index()
{
    $kategori = DB::table('kategoris')->get();
    $data = [];
    $label = [];
    foreach ($kategori as $i => $v) {
        $value[$i] = DB::table('produks')->where('id_kategori',$v->id)->count();
        $label[$i] = $v->nama;
    }
    return view('home')->with('value',json_encode($value))->with('label',json_encode($label));
}
```

Comment: @IKetutWidhiAdnyana It help you?

Comment: ya.. your answer helpfull

Answer (score 1):

```
return view('home')
               ->with(['value'=>json_encode($value),'label'=>json_encode($label)]);
```